# Why there's a eclipse/netbeans version for Windows if java "run everywhere"

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, netbeans

I'm a beginner at java programming and studied about the "write once, run anywhere" thing, but I noticed that when I download Eclipse or Netbeans IDEs (written in Java) there's a version for Windows and other versions for others OS's.

If a java program "runs anywhere" there shouldn't be "versions" (at my first thought). I searched and found that it's because (at least Eclipse, don't know about Netbeans) the program uses a different GUI library that does not work cross plataform.

So my questions are:

1) Why use a library that takes off one of the strongest features in java? Is it faster/ prettier?
2) Are there other ways, except the use of that library, that makes a java program don't work cross-plataform?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any use of native libraries will make a Java app non portable; and GUI toolkits are a prime candidate for that. They are indeed both prettier and faster.

Comment: For NetBeans it's mainly convenience because people are used to starting `.exe` rather than `.bat` files. There are some native libraries in NetBeans to support debuging (remote) applications. Eclipse however **is** platform dependent because of the SWT GUI toolkit which is not written in Java, but uses native libraries (.dll, .so)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I download Eclipse or Netbeans IDEs (written in Java) there's a
>   version for Windows and other versions for others OS's.
>
> If a java program "runs anywhere" there shouldn't be "versions" (at my
>   first thought).

### Eclipse

Eclipse uses [SWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit), which uses the ***native*** GUI libraries, therefore you need a Version for each OS / platform.

### NetBeans

In contrast to Eclipse, NetBeans uses standard-java [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) for GUI, so no need for native GUI libraries.

Here you are not correct: You **can** download a OS-specific version (eg. Windows / Linux / Mac OS), but you *don't have to*!

For downloading just select **"OS independed Zip"** as ***Platform***. You'll get a ZIP archive you can extract and run on every supported platform. However, on Windows you have to run the exe, on Linux the shellscript to start the IDE (check `bin` directory).

The main feature of the os specific versions are their installers, the resulting NetBeans is mostly common to all.

> 1) Why use a library that takes off one of the strongest features in
>   java? Is it faster/ prettier?

Just search for SWT / Swing comparison (and discussion about pros / cons).

> 2) Are there other ways, except the use of that library, that makes a
>   java program don't work cross-plataform?

Yes, everything that depends on something platform specific.

Examples:

- JNA / JNI (java native calls)
- Paths (`C:/whatever` won't work on Linux, while `/home/whatever` wont work on Windows)
- Env. variables etc.
- calling other programs

Just look for something like *"how to keep java cross-platform"* and do the opposite of very recommendation.

In general, java does a good job here, but with enough bad intentions you can kill any "cross-platform" development ;-)